# Angular : NGXS : WebSocket updated the state but not UI

Tags: angular, typescript, websocket, state-management, ngxs

I'm using NGXS to implement the state management in my Angular project, and the states are updated by the WebSocket, a plugin of NGXS

What I implemented:

model.ts

```
export interface Student {
  id: string;
  name: string;
  passed: boolean;
}
```

student.action.ts

```
export class GetStudents{
 ...
}
export class UpdateStatus {
  static readonly type = '[Student] Update Status';
  constructor( studentId: string ) {}
}
```

student.state.ts

```
...
export class StudentStateModel {
  students: Student[];
}

@State<StudentStateModel>({
  name: 'student',
  defaults: {
    students: []
  }
})

@Action(GetStudents)
... 

@Action(UpdateStatus)
  updateStatus(
    { getState, setState }: StateContext<StudentStateModel>,
    { studentId }: UpdateStatus
  ) {
  
    const students = getState().students;
    const index = students.findIndex((i) => i.id === studentId);

    setState((state: ApprovalStateModel) => {
      state.students[index].passed = true;
      return state;
    });
  }
...
```

I implement 2 components (parent and child):

1/ the parent component keeps the list of students

```
students$: Observable<any>; // Get list of Students from Store GetStudents
```

students.component.html

```
<div *ngFor= "let student of students$ | async">
    <app-student-detail
      [student] = "student"
    ></app-student-detail>
  </div>
```

2/ the child component keeps the student detail, it includes an input

```
@Input() student: Student = null;
```

student-detail.component.html

```
<div *ngIf="student">
    <p>Id: {{student.id}}</p>
    <p>Name: {{student.name}}</p>
    <p>Result: {{student.passed}} </p>
  </div
```

I use the WebSocket plugin to update the student state, I sent a message

```
 {"type": "[Student] Update Status", "studentId" : "10001"}
```

Result:

From the log, the state is updated successfully with passed = true for student id 10001, but from UI, the Result is not updated.

Something wrong with my implementation,  any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Are you dispatching the action?

Comment: I used websocket to dispatch the action. https://www.ngxs.io/plugins/websocket

Comment: Just realized you're mutating your state. `state.students[index].passed = true;` can't do that...

Comment: @Richard.Davenport Thanks for your hint, I fixed my problem ... yes, you are right, I forgot to add @ImmutableContext() in action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a state operator to update the state. For example, you could use the `updateItem` to find and update an item in an array:

```js
import { patch, updateItem } from '@ngxs/store/operators';
    
...

@Action(UpdateStatus)
updateStatus(ctx: StateContext<StudentStateModel>, { studentId }: UpdateStatus) {
  ctx.setState(
    patch({
      students: updateItem<Student>(
        student => student.studentId === studentId,
        student => ({
          ...student,
          passed: true
        })
      )
    })
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, yes, the issue came from the mutation, I will accept your answer, and also share my workaround is using the @ngxs-labs/immer-adapter